# Memory Efficient implementation of corner point grids in Java3D/OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, grid, java-3d

Say I have NX*NY*NZ cells in a [corner-point-grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner-point_grid). I have also a mask of NX*NY*NZ booleans that gives me which cells of the grid I have to draw.

I would like to create an efficient indexed quad array in Java3D (or OpenGL, it does not matter at the end, since the concepts below are the same) using less memory as possible.

For sake of simplicity I'm skipping to declare the normals of each face and really I do not need them since I'm using a flat shading and no lighting.

I have a color for each cell (this is based on a per-cell property).

Thus I'm listing the faces I need to draw based on the cells mask.

I find myself repeating the same point (belonging to different faces) several times to be able to give each face a color.

Do you have any hint about how to make it more efficient?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the boolean mask, that could be exploited? E.g. never an "on" cell above an "off" cell? any constraints on the camera location or angle (e.g. always above a "surface")?

Comment: Hi LarsH. No, sorry, no constraint on boolean mask. I also tried to use a flood fill algorithm in 3D, but it was not so fast to make me understand whether the active cells set was restricted to a closed surface or not... So I end up drawing all faces that stay between an "on" cell and an "off" cell in any direction. About camera location, no constraints as well: the observer should be able to watch the grid from any angle. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have many options:

First, you could use a geometry shader to dynamically generate vertices, though this will only work if you have a fairly high end system.

Another option is to draw your object in multiple passes.  If you don't care about fill rate, you could just draw a collection of quads along the xyz planes which read into the volume array directly.

Following along the same line of reasoning, you could also ray cast the object to render it in a fragment shader, which could be faster depending on the size of NX, NY and NZ.

If you have to draw quads, another possibility is to store the vertex data separately, then use vertex-shader read-from-texture to determine the color coordinates.  You could split up drawing the whole grid over multiple rendering passes.

If you need to store the color data with the vertices, the last thing you could try is storing 4 copies of each color together with 2-components for the coordinate of each vertex in the x-z direction.  To draw the whole array you would do 6 passes, one for each face of the cube.  This could be substantially optimized by pruning out the passes for the faces which are invisible.

The ultimate choice of course depends on the amount of data you need to draw, the type of hardware you are targeting and how much work you want to spend on this project.